# TTStyle as instance variable error

Tags: ios, three20

I declare `TTStyle` in my class and it has error :

```
 expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'TTStyle'
```

I don't know what's wrong with it.

Can any one help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to import the Three20Style.h header. If you have three20 set up the standard way you do this by

```
#import "Three20Style/Three20Style.h"
```

before `@interface`.